# Книги по JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ооп, книги

Подскажите, какие еще есть хорошие и современные книги по JavaScript, кроме Флэнагана, Стоянова и учебника И.Кантора? Где рассматриваются различные тонкости языка, интересные приемы программирования и т.д.

P.S. И вообще какие есть хорошие книги по ООП?

Comment: А чем вышеуказанные авторы не угодили? Классика же..

Comment: @deivan, a не говорил, что они мне не угодили. Я их читал. Просто хочется что-то новое узнать.

Answer (score 3):

- «Высокопроизводительный JavaScript» от Николаса Закаса. Здесь описаны техники оптимизации джаваскрипт кода, c графиками, с примерами. Оч советую.
- «JavaScript: Сильные стороны» от Дугласа Крокфорда. Книга о том как сделать джаваскрипт код выразительнее :). Использую эту книгу как справочник. Книга не для начинающих.

Comment: Спасибо. Обязательно почитаю. А про ООП что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 2):

Это не книга, но тут куча тонкостей http://wtfjs.com/

Comment: @mountpoint, спасибо.